# Enter an address in the google chrome address field when narrator is activated

Tags: google-chrome, accessibility, narrator

Every key is a shortcut when using the Windows screen reader Narrator, but how do I enter text in the chrome address bar?

If I have the google page open, I can search for something in that input field, but it seems I cannot enter an address in the address bar. Then narrators shortcuts for every keystroke will be activated instead. Is this a browser bug?

Is there a way to temprarily disable the hotkeys when narrator is still activated?

Comment: Is it the Windows Narrator?

Comment: Yes, do I have to use another tag?

Comment: The tag is fine for me. It was just to make sure that you were asking about Windows Narrator and not something else.

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: Don''t know why it is such a pain to enter/start typing on Chrome address bar when the narrator is on. But a possible workaround (not the most elegant) is to stop the narrator when you are at the address bar, type what you want then Enter, restart the narrator. So CTRL+L to reach the address bar, Win+CTRL+Enter (Narrator key + ESC) to stop the narrator), type your url or search, Enter, then again Win+CTRL+Enter to start the narrator.

Comment: Temporarily stopping narrator is a no. It seems to be a shortcoming of chrome. Edge was ok.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that there is no problem entering URLs on Edge's address bar.

Answer (score 0):

After you press ctrl+l to access address bar, press Narrator Key+Space Bar to turn Scan Mode Off.  Then you are able to type in the address bar.  HTH